# SQLite and forking safely

Tags: c, sqlite

I have an application where there are many readers of a SQLite database executing in parallel, each in their own process. The processes can fork ... and are able to do so after the SQLite connection has been established.

I'd like to write a fork handler so that when the parent process forks, all of the SQLite state is "refreshed" in the child process ... meaning that all prepared statements, database connections, and other resources are immediately discarded without cleanup.

As a library, SQLite manages its own memory and other resources so in theory is possible.

In effect what I want to do is duplicate the non-SQLite application state when forking, but have the SQLite state that would be present if the program had started executing via `exec*` rather than `fork`.

If possible, what I want to do would something like this:

```
void sqlite_refresh(void)
{
     // discard all sqlite-specific state
     // make all sqlite3_db, sqlite3_stmt &c pointers NULL
     return;
}

// call this code somewhere
pthread_atfork(
     /* prepare */ NULL,
     /* parent */  NULL,
     /* child */   sqlite_refresh
);
```

On the SQLite website, there's some commentary on not using fork, but it seems to be written with the assumption that the programmers intends to interact with the SQLite library in the child process after forking.

SQLite gives the following ominous warning in [its documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) about using fork:

> Do not open an SQLite database connection, then fork(), then try to
>   use that database connection in the child process. All kinds of
>   locking problems will result and you can easily end up with a corrupt
>   database. SQLite is not designed to support that kind of behavior. Any
>   database connection that is used in a child process must be opened in
>   the child process, not inherited from the parent.
>
> Do not even call sqlite3_close() on a database connection from a child
>   process if the connection was opened in the parent. It is safe to
>   close the underlying file descriptor, but the sqlite3_close()
>   interface might invoke cleanup activities that will delete content out
>   from under the parent, leading to errors and perhaps even database
>   corruption.

It says [here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6) that

> Under Unix, you should not carry an open SQLite database across a
>   fork() system call into the child process.

Answer (score 0):

The child process must not do *anything* with the connection/statement objects that it got from the parent. This means that your `sqlite_refresh()` function must be empty, or that it just sets all pointers to NULL.
(This implies that the memory is leaked.)

It would be a better idea to not have an open connection when forking.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question, but for why it is unsafe to use the database connection after calling `fork()`:

SQLite uses file system locks to handle process concurrency, but these locks are mostly `advisory locks` instead of `mandatory locks`, i.e., if a process is not aware of the lock, then it can still access (read or write) the file without any issues. For a spawned child process, it is not aware of the lock (as the connection has already been created in the program, parent process and child process are the same program until the child process involves `exec_*` functions), thus it can do anything with the database file without any restrictions, which is totally unsafe.

For more info about `advisory locks` and `mandatory locks`, see [File locking in Linux](https://gavv.net/articles/file-locks/).